# Numpy array to raster in python / GDAL

Tags: python, gdal

I have raw .dat file which I need to convert to a raster.
I am currently using numpy to read the file

```
data = np.fromfile('gsmap_gauge_now.20200805.0400.dat',dtype = np.float32)
```

The coverage of this raster is from 60 N - 60 S with grid of [3600 x 1200]

How do I achieve this using GDAL or any other linux supported tool ?

Comment: You can use GDAL, create a single band float32 raster and wirte the numpy array to the band with writearray.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719096/create-geotiff-gdal-from-np-array

Comment: Thanks @Zoltan , this was helpful